# web2py orderby datetime out of order

Tags: datetime, sql-order-by, web2py

I'm writing a simple web app in web2py that stores and retrieves some data from a database. To keep the entries in chronological order, my table has an attribute which stores a date time. Like so:

```
db.define_table('tablename',
           Field( ....
           ....
           ....
           Field('created_on','datetime', default=request.now, writable=False),
           Field('last_modified','datetime', default=request.now, update=request.now),
           )
```

Then when I request the data, I set the orderby attribute to last_modified:

```
rows = db().select(db.tablename.ALL, orderby=db.tablename.last_modified)
```

Then, I pass the results onto a Json dictionary object. Like so:

```
I'm passing them into a JSON dictionary object.Like so: 



d = { r.index_id : {'index_id':r.index_id,
                                 ....
                                 ....
                                 'comments':r.comments,
                                 'created_on':r.created_on,
                                 'last_modified':r.last_modified}
          for r in rows}

    return response.json(dict(entry_dict=d))
```

When I get the response from the server, I return the dict to my ractive object.

```
MAIN.set('data_entries', data['entry_dict']);
```

Then, I render the results in ractive:

```
{% #data_entries:index_id%}
              <tr class = "datarow" onclick="window.document.location='{% url+ '/'+ index_id %}';">
                  <td>{% index_id %}</td>
                  ....
                  <td>{% last_modified %}</td>
              </tr>
            {% /data_entries %}
```

However, when the data is returned to the webapp, I get to following:

[image: These are the time-stamps returned by the app looks like I have em in the wrong order.]
Am I doing this right?

Comment: How are you generating the display once you have `rows`?

Comment: I just updated my post with that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, dictionaries do not preserve order, so when you convert the `d` dictionary to JSON, you will not necessarily get the keys in the order of the original `Rows` object. You could instead use an `OrderedDict`, but it doesn't appear you really need a dictionary anyway -- just create a list (using the `as_list` method):

```
    return response.json(dict(entry_dict=rows.as_list()))
```

Then in Ractive, change:

```
{% #data_entries:index_id %}
```

to:

```
{% #data_entries %}
```

It doesn't appear you need the index value within each loop. Instead, you will be able to access the `index_id` field of each record as part of the data context of the section.